# Why does this version tag cause an error?

Tags: go

In my `go.mod` file, I have:

```
require (
    // ... editted for brevity
    github.com/Liquid-Labs/catalyst-firewrap v2.0.0-prototype.3
    // ... 
)
```

When I tried to build another package dependent on this package, I get: `invalid module: github.com/Liquid-Labs/catalyst-firewrap should be v0 or v1, not v2 (v2.0.0-prototype.3)`.

There was a rewrite back before go went modular, and I wasn't tagging stuff back then, so there is no `v1`... is that the problem? I'm not having any luck finding an explanation of the underlying problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Go modules wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#semantic-import-versioning):

> If the module is version v2 or higher, the major version of the module
>   must be included as a `/vN` at the end of the module paths used in
>   go.mod files (e.g., `module github.com/my/mod/v2`, `require github.com/my/mod/v2 v2.0.0`)
>   and in the package import path (e.g.,
>   `import "github.com/my/mod/v2/mypkg"`).

The same document quotes the rationale from the official Go FAQ:

> Packages intended for public use should try to maintain backwards
>   compatibility as they evolve. The Go 1 compatibility guidelines are a
>   good reference here: don't remove exported names, encourage tagged
>   composite literals, and so on. If different functionality is required,
>   add a new name instead of changing an old one. If a complete break is
>   required, create a new package with a new import path.

and:

> If an old package and a new package have the same import path, the new
>   package must be backwards compatible with the old package.